# Maven Fabric.io : Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, fabric.io

I cant seem to access the Fabric Io behind the proxy even though I have checked connection by setting the appropriate proxy (both http and https ) in the Android Studio.

In my Android Studio I can even see the Fabric Certificate , but still i get the

[image]

Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What I am missing here? WHat else I can try?
Thanks in Advance

Is there any Test I could run on the URL?